# High cpu useage 100% with random PID in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cpu

I’m facing problem on my ubuntu laptop running on version 16.04. It is recently consuming high cpu almost +100% in 2 cpu cores. Also flooding the upload and download link when wifi is connected which results in unavailable of network.

I tried killing the process but it results it creating a new process with root user. Tried all the available solutions not didn’t get any results.

It also creating random executable file in /usr/bin

[screenshot of the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7lP1.jpg)

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/607323/unusual-behave-virus-like

Comment: Maybe it is not duplicate, because my command are random, in the image , its cat resolve.conf but its random totally.

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate, but you need to do forensics and see what the parent processes are, and similar. Does your PC have a public facing IP address? It does look a bit like you've been rooted.